# How React functional component can still be "pure function" when we can use useEffect hook to make side Effect in it?

Tags: reactjs

How React functional component can still be "pure function" when we can use useEffect hook to make side effect in it? can somebody explain that situation ? is react in that situation still a "pure function" ? thanks a lot

Comment: I'd say so, because the hooks don't trigger side effects which influence other code outside of the function component. Not sure if this is 100% correct according to the definition of "pure" functions.

Comment: but i just have heard that Data fetching is also side effect ( it can't be true , pls help me to confirm)
then we still can use data fetching in useEffect hook